# Appropriate reference system for small-scale mapping of the Middle East

Tags: coordinate-system, cartography, thematic-map, middle-east

I want to create a thematic map of the Middle East that displays certain historic places and regions on a small-scale map (between 1:6.000.0000 and 1:12.000.000). The map has to center the boundary region between Iran, Afghanistan and Turkmenistan (about 60°E, 36°N) and possibly surrounding countries as well. It should have sufficient quality in order illustrate a scientific publication, i.e. thesis.

I am not sure about which coordinate reference system to use. UTM seems improper, since my region includes more than one UTM zone. My data is based on the WGS84 datum. So far I figured out that Lambert Conformal Conic projection may be the best, but even so I am not sure about which system to use.

Any suggestions?

EDIT (2020): I think that it was quite inappropriate to mark this question as "already answered by" a generic technical question about CRS definition in GIS, as I was trying to raise a cartographic discussion about a very specific region and use case at this time.

Comment: Try the Projection Wizard, that should get you pretty close: http://projectionwizard.org/

Comment: GIS SE isn't chartered for discussions. It would be closed today as *opinion-based*